# Discovering Nodejs promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I would like to know if there is a way to find out easily which methods I'm using return promises. As I'm using a lot of libraries and don't want to go sifting through each one to find out if I can .then() or .catch() or put my method in a try-catch block.

I'm getting the now well known:

> (node:23423) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)

Every time this error occurs the stack trace doesn't point to the lines in my files where the error occurs, leaving me in the dark about where I'm not handling this correctly. To that end, I will go through all my scripts, but I'm wondering what the most efficient way to go about this is.

Comment: chances are it's in code you have a `.then` but no `.catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodejs emit an [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) in this case.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p);
  console.log('reason:', reason);
});
```

Listening to this event allows you to determine where this Promise was created and at which part an `await` or `.then`/`.catch` is missing.

While coding you need to be always sure if the API/library uses Promises, callbacks if it is sync or event based. Each library should be consistent about that or at least make it clear by the naming of the functions. If the library is not clear about that, you should consider not using it.

There is no automatic way to figure out where a `then` or `try` catch block is missing. A way to minimize the problem is to create unit test and to reach a code coverage of 100% in your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A lot of libraries aren't clear. I don't usually unit test personal projects, but clearly I'm getting to that point! :)

Answer (score 1):

In general there isn't a *solution* for this thing - you need to be aware of what functions your own code is calling and deal with it. The same as you have to do with exceptions.

Yo might get a sense of what code causes issues via the `unhandledRejection` approach, but you'll never be 100% sure with it.